# Conda virtual enviroment and packages installed

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, environment

My question is simple. Suppose I install two different conda environments with two different software that both have as dependencies numpy version 1.16 (for example). Is numpy installed twice?. I mean one different download for each environment, thus replicating the installation of numpy.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about anaconda, but for `pip` it's downloaded once, cached globally and installed twice locally (into every virtual env). This is because network traffic is usually more expensive than disk space. And disk space these days is usually so cheap nobody cares about multiple installation of the same libraries into different virtual envs. People run virtual machines and docker containers in dozens, that is they have multiple copies of operating systems, system libraries, programming languages — who'd care about an additional small library?

Comment: This is answered a few times on here already. Depending on your operating system, conda does its best to hard link files from the "cache" (called `pkgs` usually) directory into the appropriate environment. Thus, the disk space is (usually) only taken up once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. conda uses hardlinks when possible. But if your two environments use different Python versions, for example, then conda has to install different [builds of numpy](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy/files).

Anyway, when using conda, you should not worry about disk space while deciding whether to create a new environment. If you have two projects that require different sets of libraries, then create different conda environments for each. Anaconda will do its best to save your disk space.